# Background images disappear in IE7/8

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, background, internet-explorer-7

We're currently fixing up our corporate site but we have an issue with some background images in IE7 and 8. The pages render fine in webkit and Fox, but the backgrounds disappear in IE. Haven't quite figured out the issue - layers? doc mode? positioning? - but I am hoping another pair of eyes can help. Pages here:

http://bmobile.co.tt/plans/
and 
http://bmobile.co.tt/services/

Comment: You have special style sheets assigned in for those browsers. Are you certain you have the backgrounds properly assigned in those sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this property style from your style.css

```
   .plans #wrap .contentlock{
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f4f4f4',GradientType=0 )
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! As easy as that! Thanks, monzymirza!